# No sound with headphones on Debian 12

Tags: linux, audio, debian

I am still relatively new to Linux so please bear with me. I have been trying to get my (3.5mm jack) headphones working with Debian 12. Earbuds didn't seem to work either. Alsamixer and pavucontrol both are showing that the headphones are connected as well as the output, but I'm not hearing anything besides noise coming from the headphones. I have tried installing several alsa packages, trying to install `alsa-base` returned this message and so did `alsa-firmware-loaders`.

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package alsa-base
```

I've had the same issue with Ubuntu as well, I believe Ubuntu worked with USB headphones though which I no longer have access to. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated, then upgraded the default installation from the ISO before trying this? As in `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` ?  You error gives me the feeling that you haven't.